# Why is photoshop adding a white stoke to my work after I save it as a gif, but not as a png?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

For some reason Photoshop is adding a weird white stroke (which I'm not to fond of) to my finished work after I save it. However this only happens when I save it as a .gif, otherwise the image is completely transparent and how I want it.

Example:

Gif: (open image in a new tab to see the white line)

[image]

Not Gif (png):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gif is supports binary transparency, ie transparent or not. Where there is a transition, it needs to apply a matte color to fake alpha channel transparency. The default matte color is white. Set it to whatever your background color is and you won't notice it.

PNG supports true transparent pixels, ie alpha channel transparency. It renders well, but comes with the cost of no animation support. That's where gif still reigns supreme.

Comment: I have a feeling wherever this was going only supports gifs, but I wanted to mention that one workaround to the transparency limitations of a gif is to create a png sequence (every single frame as a separate png file) that is then animated using javascript or css. With this image you could even use a hybrid of his method in order to save in load times. Since the animation doesn't extend to the very edges, you could save the image as one static png and crop/export the animated plate as a png sequence (Or just a gif if the quality holds up) and just use css to overlay it on top of the static png